# JSF : Unable to convert string 'width:100%;' to class javax.el.ValueExpression for attribute style

Tags: jsp, jsf, properties, websphere, el

this is the jsp page.
actually this 'width:100%' element is converting it into the ASCII code(`&#39;width:100&#37;&#59;&#39;`) so its treating as a property can anyone has any solution for this?

```
<%@ taglib prefix="h" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"%>
<%@ taglib prefix="f" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"%>

<f:subview id="header">
    <h:panelGrid style="width:100%;" border="0" cellpadding="0"
        cellspacing="0">
        <f:verbatim>
            <table class="heading" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0"
                width="100%">
                <tr>
                    <td width="41">
                        <img src="images/logo01.gif" border="0" />
                    </td>
                    <td nowrap="nowrap" style="padding:7px 0px 0px 0px;">
                        Administration&nbsp;&nbsp;
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </f:verbatim>
    </h:panelGrid>
</f:subview>
```

below is the error stack trace.

```
    at com.ibm.ws.util.ThreadPool$Worker.run(ThreadPool.java:1691)
Caused by: com.ibm.ws.jsp.JspCoreException: Unable to convert string **'width:100%;' to class javax.el.ValueExpression** for attribute style: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Property Editor not registered with the PropertyEditorManager
    at org.apache.jasper.runtime.JspRuntimeLibrary.getValueFromPropertyEditorManager(JspRuntimeLibrary.java:939)
    at com.ibm._jsp._header_5F_admin._jspx_meth_h_panelGrid_0(_header_5F_admin.java:155)
    at com.ibm._jsp._header_5F_admin._jspx_meth_f_subview_0(_header_5F_admin.java:213)
    at com.ibm._jsp._header_5F_admin._jspService(_header_5F_admin.java:90)
    ... 78 more

[3/23/17 2:20:41:202 CDT] 00000043 servlet       E com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper service SRVE0014E: Uncaught service() exception root cause faces: com.ibm.websphere.servlet.error.ServletErrorReport: com.ibm.ws.jsp.JspCoreException: Unable to convert string **(`&#39;width:100&#37;&#59;&#39;`) to class javax.el.ValueExpression** for attribute style: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Property Editor not registered with the PropertyEditorManager
    at org.apache.jasper.runtime.PageContextImpl.handlePageException(PageContextImpl.java:695)
    at com.ibm._jsp._header_5F_admin._jspService(_header_5F_admin.java:98)
    at com.ibm.ws.jsp.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:99)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:668)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.service(ServletWrapper.java:1225)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.handleRequest(ServletWrapper.java:775)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.handleRequest(ServletWrapper.java:457)
```

I am using Myfaces 1.1.1. Please let me know what will be the issue.

Comment: Have you tried to assign `width` value without % sign?

Comment: yes i tried, its not working